# change the items in a ListView from another fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-fragments

I have two fragments, lets call them Fragment A and Fragment B, which are a part of a NavigationDrawer (this is the activity they a bound to).  In Fragment A I have a button.  When this button is pressed, I would like another item added to the ListView in Fragment B.

What is the best way to do this? Use Intents, SavedPreferences, making something public(?) or something else?

EDIT 5: 20/7/13 This is with srains latest code

This is the `NavigationDrawer` that I use to start the fragments:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Navigation_Drawer extends FragmentActivity {

    public DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout; // Creates a DrawerLayout called_.
    public ListView mDrawerList;
    public ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private String[] mNoterActivities; // This creates a string array called _.

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

// Just setting up the navigation drawer

    } // End of onCreate

// Removed the menu


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) { 

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        if (position == 0) {
            Fragment qnfragment = new QuickNoteFragment(); 
            ((FragmentBase) qnfragment).setContext(this);
            Bundle args = new Bundle(); // Creates a bundle called args
            args.putInt(QuickNoteFragment.ARG_nOTERACTIVITY_NUMBER, position); 

            qnfragment.setArguments(args);

            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, qnfragment).commit();



        } else if (position == 3) {
            Fragment pendViewPager = new PendViewPager(); // This is a ViewPager that includes HistoryFragment
            ((FragmentBase) pendViewPager).setContext(this);
            Bundle args = new Bundle();

            pendViewPager.setArguments(args);
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, pendViewPager).commit();
        }

    // Update title etc
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { // Used for the NavDrawer toggle
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) { // Used for the NavDrawer toggle
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

This is QuickNoteFragment:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class QuickNoteFragment extends FragmentBase implements OnClickListener {

    public static final String ARG_nOTERACTIVITY_NUMBER = "noter_activity";

    Button b_create;
// removed other defining stuff

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.quicknote, container, false);
        int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_nOTERACTIVITY_NUMBER);
        String noter_activity = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.noter_array)[i];
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        setRetainInstance(true);

        b_create = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.qn_b_create);

        // Removed other stuff

        getActivity().setTitle(noter_activity);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.qn_b_create:

                              String data = "String data";
                DataModel.getInstance().addItem(data);

            break;
        }
    }

@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection

        }
    }

    public interface OnItemAddedHandler { // Srains code
        public void onItemAdded(Object data);
    }
}
```

This is HistoryFragment (Remember it is part of a `ViewPager`):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.RiThBo.noter.QuickNoteFragment.OnItemAddedHandler;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HistoryFragment extends FragmentBase implements OnItemAddedHandler {

    ListView lv;
    List<Map<String, String>> planetsList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    SimpleAdapter simpleAdpt;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.history, container, false);
        initList();


        ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        simpleAdpt = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), planetsList,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] { "planet" },
                new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });

        lv.setAdapter(simpleAdpt);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentAdapter, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                // We know the View is a TextView so we can cast it

                TextView clickedView = (TextView) view;

                Toast.makeText(
                        getActivity(),
                        "Item with id [" + id + "]  - Position [" + position
                                + "] - Planet [" + clickedView.getText() + "]",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });
        registerForContextMenu(lv);

        return view;

    }

    private void initList() {

        // We populate the planets

        planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "Mercury"));
        planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "Venus"));
        planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "Mars"));
        planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "Jupiter"));
        planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "Saturn"));
        planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "Uranus"));
        planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "Neptune"));

    }

    private HashMap<String, String> createPlanet(String key, String name) {

        HashMap<String, String> planet = new HashMap<String, String>();

        planet.put(key, name);

        return planet;

    }

    // We want to create a context Menu when the user long click on an item

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,

    ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

        AdapterContextMenuInfo aInfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;

        // We know that each row in the adapter is a Map

        HashMap map = (HashMap) simpleAdpt.getItem(aInfo.position);

        menu.setHeaderTitle("Options for " + map.get("planet"));
        menu.add(1, 1, 1, "Details");
        menu.add(1, 2, 2, "Delete");

    }
     @Override
      public void onItemAdded(Object data) {
          // to add item
          String string = String.valueOf(data);
          Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Data: " + string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", string));
      }
      @Override
    public void onStart() {
          super.onStart();

          DataModel.getInstance().setOnItemAddedHandler(this);
      }
}
```

This is FragmentBase:

```
   import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

      public class FragmentBase extends Fragment {

            private FragmentActivity mActivity; // I changed it to FragmentActivity because Activity was not working, and my `NavDrawer` is a FragmentActivity.

            public void setContext(FragmentActivity activity) {
                mActivity = mActivity;
            }

            public FragmentActivity getContext() {
                return mActivity;
            }
    }
```

This is DataModel:

```
  import android.util.Log;
    import com.xxx.xxx.QuickNoteFragment.OnItemAddedHandler;

public class DataModel {

    private static DataModel instance;
    private static OnItemAddedHandler mOnItemAddHandler;

    public static DataModel getInstance() {
        if (null == instance) {
            instance = new DataModel();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void setOnItemAddedHandler(OnItemAddedHandler handler) {
        mOnItemAddHandler = handler;
    }

    public void addItem(Object data) {
        if (null != mOnItemAddHandler)
            mOnItemAddHandler.onItemAdded(data);
        else {
            Log.i("is context null?", "yes!");
        }  
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Since fragments belonging to the same Activity come together, you can safely use static fields. Something like `FragmentB.adapter.add(x); FragmentBadapter.notifyDataSetChanges();`

Comment: @Archie.bpgc  Please could you expand a bit more -  don't really understand

Comment: Just make the `ListView Adapter` of **FragmentB** `static` and use it like `FragmentB.adapter.add(new item);` in **FragmentA's** Button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use `interface` and `MVC`, that will make your code much more maintainable.

First you need an interface:

```
    public interface OnItemAddedHandler {
        public void onItemAdded(Object data);
    }
```

Then, you will need a data model:

```
    public class DataModel {

        private static DataModel instance;
        private static OnItemAddedHandler mOnItemAddHandler;

        public static DataModel getInstance() {
            if (null == instance) {
                instance = new DataModel();
            }
            return instance;
        }

        public void setOnItemAddedHandler(OnItemAddedHandler handler) {
            mOnItemAddHandler = handler;
        }

        public void addItem(Object data) {
            if (null != mOnItemAddHandler)
                mOnItemAddHandler.onItemAdded(data);
        }
    }
```

When you click the button, you can add data into the datamodel:

```
    Object data = null;
    DataModel.getInstance().addItem(data);
```

Then, the `FragmentB` implements the interface `OnItemAddedHandler` to add item

```
    public class FragmentB implements OnItemAddedHandler {

        @Override
        public void onItemAdded(Object data) {
            // to add item
        }
    }
```

also, When the `FragmentB` start, you should register itself to DataModel:

```
    public class FragmentB implements OnItemAddedHandler {

        @Override
        public void onItemAdded(Object data) {
            // to add item
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();

            DataModel.getInstance().setOnItemAddedHandler(this);
        }
    }
```

You also can add `DataModel.getInstance().setOnItemAddedHandler(this);` to the `onCreate` method of `FragmentB`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    DataModel.getInstance().setOnItemAddedHandler(this);

    // do other things
}
```

**update**

you can send string simply:

```
    String data = "some string";
    DataModel.getInstance().addItem(data);
```

then on `FragementB`

```
    public class FragmentB implements OnItemAddedHandler {

        @Override
        public void onItemAdded(Object data) {
            // get what you send into method DataModel.getInstance().addItem(data);
            String string = String.valueOf(data);
        }
    }
```

**update**

OK. You have add `DataModel.getInstance().setOnItemAddedHandler(this)` in `onCreateView` method, so there is no need to add it in `onStart()` method. You can remove the whole `onStart` method.

`onStart` will be called on the fragment start, we do not need to call it in `onCreateView`. And on `onItemAdded` will be call when call the method `DataModel.getInstance().addItem(data)`,  we do not need to call it in `onCreateView` neither.

so,  you can remove the code below from `onCreateView` method:

```
   DataModel.getInstance().setOnItemAddedHandler(this);
   // remove the methods below
   // onItemAdded(getView());
   // onStart();
```

You have another fragment where there is a button, you can add the codes below in the clickhandler function:

```
String data = "some string";
DataModel.getInstance().addItem(data);
```

**update3**

I think the `HistoryFragment` has been detached after you when to `QuickNoteFragment`
You can add code to `HistoryFragment` to check:

```
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    Log.i("test", String.format("onDetach! %s", getActivity() == null));
}
```

**update4**

I think `HistoryFragment` and `QuickNoteFragment` should has an parent class, named `FragmentBase`:

```
    public class FragmentBase extends Fragment {

        private Activity mActivity;

        public void setContext(Activity activity) {
            mActivity = mActivity;
        }

        public Activity getContext() {
            return mActivity;
        }
    }
```

`HistoryFragment` and `QuickNoteFragment` extends `FragmentBase`. Then when you switch between them, you can call `setContext` to set a Activity, like:

```
private void selectItem(int position) {

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    if (position == 0) {
        Fragment qnfragment = new QuickNoteFragment();
        qnfragment.setContext(this);

        // ...

    } else if (position == 1) {
        Fragment pagerFragment = new RemViewPager();
        pagerFragment.setContext(this);

        // ...
    }
}
```

now, we can get a non-null activity in `HistoryFragment` by calling `getContext`, so we can change `onItemAdded` method to:

```
  @Override
  public void onItemAdded(Object data) {
      // to add item
      String string = String.valueOf(data);
      Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Data: " + string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", string));
  }
```

I hope this would work.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much for the comprehensive guide - I will try this too

Comment: OK, I have everything running without errors, but the object is not being added ( I'm tried a String and TextView) to the listview

Comment: add some log to onItemAdded method in FragmentB to show what the data is.

Comment: That method is not being called anywhere in FragmentB

Comment: When I call onItemAdded when the data is a string, I get a FC on the button click

Comment: You can send FC to `DataModel.getInstance().addItem(FC)`,  then the data pass from method `onItemAdded(Object data)` will also be FC

Comment: Sorry I meant Force Close

Comment: I've got rid of the ForceClose, but I don't think I calling onItemAdded properly in my onCreateView.  I am doing this:  onItemAdded(getView());

Comment: http://pastie.org/private/jk4rtpql5eckn9brhibww  This is FragmentB - it is actually called HistoryFragment.  The problem is that the string returns null.  I know that i have not added the string to the listview yet, but I first wanted to get the string

Comment: I can not open the link. sure it is right? can you paste the code on you question?

Comment: Done.  I think the problem is me calling onItemAdded(getView()); in my oncreate.  If I replace getView() with "hi", the Toast test says "hi" NOT what I set as the data in FragmentA

Comment: I updated the answer again, change your `fragmentB`, check still have any questions.

Comment: OK. If there are still any questions, feel free to comment here. Do not forget to remove `onStart` method and do not call `onStart` in the `onCreateView` method. Good luck.

Comment: Thank for sticking with me :-), but that still doesn't work for me :-(. The toast in onItemAdded() does not appear

Comment: where you call this `DataModel.getInstance().addItem(data);` ?

Comment: where do you call this `DataModel.getInstance().addItem(data);`

Comment: In my other fragment when the button is pressed.  I will add the code of that fragment if necessary

Comment: Done.  I removed quite a lot from Fragment A that was not necessary (I think :-))

Comment: Your code seems pretty good. Wait for a moment. I am trying this code on my app.

Comment: It works well on my app, does this code `case R.id.qn_b_create:` hitted? Can you add a breakpoint to the code, then debug it, follow the code, see where it will go.

Comment: It always has before I added your code - I've been using it for ages.  I will test again

Comment: Yes, the button creates a notification and that works fine.  Howver, if go to HistoryFragment and then back to QuickNoteFragment I get a nullpointerexception and the app Force Closes

Comment: Do I need to move the DataModel bit to my activity rather than fragments?

Comment: you can see the exception info in logcat

Comment: I added it to the question

Comment: From the exception stack trace, we can see `onItemAdded` has been called. But the method `getActivity()` return null, so the nullpointerexception trigger. How do you switch your fragments? When you go to `HistoryFragment `, is the  `QuickNoteFragment` still alive?

Comment: No, I don't think so.  I am using the NavigationDrawer api and every time I click on a fragment, onCreateView is called for that fragment.

Comment: I think after you went to `HistoryFragment`, `getActivity()` may return null in `QuickNoteFragment`. Add `Log.i("test", getActivity() == null);` before `Toast.makeText(...` to see what will print out in logcat?

Comment: Because it is true, it means that my QuickNoteFragment has been detached from the activity.  Do you know a way around that, or to reattach it from HistoryFragment?

Comment: How do you change switch the fragments, would you paste the core code?

Comment: I did some more logcats and got a nullpointerexception at this (which is in QuickNoteFragment):  public void addItem(Object data) {
             if (null != mOnItemAddHandler)
                 mOnItemAddHandler.onItemAdded(data);
         }

Comment: I haven't - I just read the logcat of the force close.  But I think I found the issue! I tried to make a Toast in  "public static class DataModel" But there was getActivity() for the context had an error because the class was STATIC.  If I remove the "static" part, getActivity() is no longer null, so the code should work.  However I get errors on "instance", "mOnItemHandler" and "getInstance()" because they are static.

Comment: Basically if I just copy and paste the code in your answer I get errors because there are static items in a non-static method.  I did an "auto-fix" which changed the DataModel class to static but in doing so, getActivity() doesn't work.  Is it possible to change your code to make it work?

Comment: that make some sense. you should change `public static class DataModel` to `public class DataModel`, you should put the code in a single file, instead of with `QuickNoteFragment`

Comment: If I remove the static, I get errors on the other things like "instance" which have been made static.  If I remove the static from them I get an error on getInstance() becasue that should apparently be static

Comment: only change `public static class DataModel` to `public class DataModel`, then put code to a sigle file: `DataModel.java`, do remove the other `static`.

Comment: I think the issue if the `HistoryFragment` may have been detached. I updated the answer, you can add some codes to check. If that is true. I have the solution.

Comment: Sorry - It's getting a bit late for me.  I will try again tomorrow.  Thank you for your help so far :-)

Comment: I `update` the answer and added **update4**. If it is convenient, you can put your code on github, I can fork you project and do some code to solve this issue. Your also can send your code to my email if you want.

Comment: That still doesn't work.  My NavigationDrawer class name is "Navigation_Drawer" and it extends FragmentActivity if that makes any difference...  The problem is still the same. At  public void addItem(Object data) {
        if (null != mOnItemAddHandler)
            mOnItemAddHandler.onItemAdded(data);
        else {
         Log.i("Is is happening", "Yes!"); // Therefore we know that something is still wrong
        } 
    } I will upload my latest code.

Comment: OK: I have uploaded the new stuff with your UPDATE4.  I think I still have the same problems although ther are no errors about the static stuff this time as DataModel is in its own "file"

Comment: Would this answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5114361/2442638  I will try it

Comment: I saw your code, I looks like total the same with mine, still FC?

Comment: I saw your code, It looks like total the same with mine, still FC?

Comment: Yes.  The way I got it was. Open app -> It automatically starts QuickNoteFragment.  I press the button -> I open HistiryFragment (part of ViewPager) via the NavDrawer.  I do NOT get the toast with the string data. -> I go back to QuickNoteFragment -> I press the Button -> Force Close every time I repeat this

Comment: Is that convenient for you to put your project to `github`? or send it to my email. There might be some other question which we didnot notice.

Comment: yes, or you can make it small but make sure this issue can reproduce.

Comment: OK - I will have a go

Comment: `liaohuqiu@gmail.com`

Comment: I shall go for dinner with my friends. If you have posted the code to `github` or my email. please let me know. Have a good weekend.

Comment: Thank you.  I will try to post it on GitHub but it might take me a while. I started another question in the meantime and got this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/17761012/2442638  But I don't understand where I should call setContext(), as I have already done this (incorrectly?) in the NavigationDrawer

Comment: I have sent you an email from rithbo1111@gmail.com  Thanks for helping

Comment: I found out the problem. The `HistoryFragment` has been detached. do you must `replace` the fragment?

Comment: Great! Than you very much!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33876/discussion-between-srain-and-rithbo)

Answer (score 1):

Some good design principals:

- An activity can know everything pubic about any Fragment it contains.
- A Fragment should not know anything about the **specific** Activities that contain it.
- A Fragment should NEVER know about other fragments that may or may not be contained in the Parent activity.

A suggested approach (informal design pattern) based on these principles.

Each fragment should declare an interface to be implemented by its parent activity:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment
{
   public interface Parent
   {
      void onMyFragmentSomeAction();
   }
   private Parent mParent;
   public onAttach(Activity activity)
   {
      mParent = (Parent) activity;
   }

   // This would actually be in a listener.  Simplifying to save typing.
   void onSomeButtonClick(View button)
   {
      mParent.onMyFragmentSomeAction();
   }
}
```

And the activity should implement the appropriate interfaces for all of its contained fragments.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity 
                        implements MyFragment.Parent,
                                   YourFragment.Parent,
                                   HisFragment.Parent
{
   [usual Activity code]
   void onMyFragmentSomeAction()
   {
     if yourFragment is showing
     {
        yourFragment.reactToSomeAction();
     }
     if hisFragment is showing
     {
        hisFragment.observeThatSomeActionHappened();
     }
     [etc]
}
```

The broadcast approach is good, too, but it's pretty heavyweight and it requires the target Fragment to know what broadcasts will be sent by the source Fragment.

Comment: Thanks for the code and info :-), I will try this if I can't get srains code to work

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Broadcast. Send a boradcast from A, and B will receive and handle it.
2. Add a public method to B, for example, `public void addListItem()`, which will add data to listview in B. Fragment A try to find the instance of Fragment B using `FragmentMananger.findFragmentByTag()` and invoke this method.

Comment: Which would you save is "better". The button will be pressed many times, will lots of broadcasts cause the battery to drain?

Comment: In FragmentA I have out  FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    fm.findFragmentByTag("FragmentB");  How do I call a public method from this.

Comment: Use FramgmentManager.findFragmentByTag(), and get a reference to Fragment B instance, write a public method addListItem() in Fragment B, and call it from A.